# Conditional highlighting of rows in tableHTML

Tags: r, tablehtml

In tableHTML: Is there a way to highlight complete rows based on one conditional column? Something like this, but also with red cells in the mpg-, cyl- and disp-columns:

```
tableHTML(mtcars[1:10,1:3]) %>%
add_css_conditional_column(conditional = "contains", 
                           value = "Hornet",
                           css = list('background-color', "red"), 
                           columns = "rownames")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the recently published version of tableHTML (version 2.1.0), there's an option to choose `logical` as a conditional type with `add_css_conditional_column`, which can be also used as a proxy for row conditional highlighting if it was applied to all columns

Basically you define the logical vector for the condition (just like the answer by clemens), and choose to apply it to all columns like so:

```
my_df <- mtcars[1:10,1:3]
conditional <- grepl("Hornet", rownames(my_df)) 

tableHTML(my_df) %>%
  add_css_conditional_column(conditional = "logical", 
                             columns = 0:ncol(my_df),
                             css = list('background-color', "red"), 
                             logical_conditions = list(conditional))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh yes, much more elegant!

Comment: Since I don't want to accept my own answer, I accept this as the second best solution. ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer myself.
Using the `add_css_row` function, the condition can be added to the `rows` parameter:

```
my_df <- mtcars[1:10,1:3]
tableHTML(my_df) %>%
add_css_row(css = list('background-color', 'red'), 
            rows = grep("Hornet", rownames(my_df)) + 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

We have the intention to include that functionality in the package, but haven't implemented it yet. It can be done with a bit of a hack though:

First, we create a logical vector for the conditional, then we create a `tableHTML` object. Then, for each column in the `tableHTML` object, we can apply a style in a loop using the function `add_css_rows_in_column`:

```r
library(tableHTML)

conditional <- grepl("Hornet", rownames(mtcars[1:10, ])) 

my_tableHTML<- mtcars[1:10,1:3] %>% 
 tableHTML()
for (i in 0:3) {
 my_tableHTML <- my_tableHTML %>% 
  add_css_rows_in_column(css = list(c("background-color"), 
                                    ifelse(conditional, "red", "")),
                         column = i)
} 

my_tableHTML
```

The result looks like this:
[image: tableHTML_result]